# Dagger 2, gradle dependencies on annotations

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm still confused about gradle dependencies I have to add for Dagger 2. Let's assume that I'm using

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
```

Do I need to use this line?

```
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Or is it better to use this dependency

```
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

I saw also that people include

```
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
```

I'm confused on all these dependencies.

Comment: I use just the first one (glassfish) and it works.

Comment: That's not very helpful actually. I use JSR 250 but I'm not very sure which one does what. My colleagues use Glassfish annotation. I'm confused

Comment: im confused too...did you(@shadox) come to know anything about it

Answer (score 0):

Dagger 2 originally used the `@Generated` annotation, which was part of the JDK but not Android. [It was removed](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/95) in recent versions of Dagger 2, so you don't need any of those extra dependencies.